# Where is ubuntu installed? Lack of space error

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

My other PC runs Ubuntu - been a while now, maybe a few years.
I get an error dialog box after start-up which says I dont have enough space, like only 2 or 300MB left. It gives me the option to analyse the HD. Im looking at the result now in the "Disk Usage Analyzer". At the top it reads; 
Total filesystem capacity: 152.3GB (used: 114.2GB, available: 38.1GB)
I have one HD with 3 partitions, I think.

So I am lost, but if yu can tell me how to tell which partition the Ubuntu system is installed on, I might be able to move some files around to try to make more space.
Thx
Greenie

Comment: You can tell which partition Ubuntu is installed upon using the terminal command `df`.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [GParted](https://gparted.org/), it's a neat tool for disk partitioning.

You can launch from the terminal with:

```
gparted
```

or install it with:

```
sudo apt install gparted
```

or you can make a live usb key: [GParted live usb](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php).

Then spot the row in the partition table corresponding to the mounting point : "/"

That will likely be the partition where your system folders are installed.

You can easily resize yours partitions and don't forget to hit the check icon for apply the operations.

Hope this can help. Cheers.